# Multi-threading OpenCV Python script

Tags: python, opencv, facial-identification

So I was approached by my boss with a project to do something rather ambitious and that was to actuate an arm with a screen on the end to the height of a user's face. How I did this was to utilize OpenCV's facial recognition library, place a square around the user's face and output the 'Y' value to the terminal. With this value, I sent high and low signals to a microcontroller which controls a stepper motor that moves the arm up, down or holds it if the height of the user is 'within range'.

I originally used the haar cascade in the program but found it was very laggy. I then switched to the LBP cascade which does run faster but is not as accurate. I found that in order for the program to not run as laggy, I would need to multithread my script.

I am an R&D guy who typically does electrical engineering, wiring, allocating, etc... I do not program so it is a miracle I have gotten this far. I have the code below and any help would be appreciated as all other forums on multithreading in Python are over my head as I cannot fully grasp the vernacular of Python.

```
import cv2
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from threading import Thread

#assigning GPIO to BCM instead of board
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#HIGH and LOW output pins to microcontroller
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
#Limit switch input buttons
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
#cascade reference for facial detection
cascPath = "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


try:
    while True: #Main loop
#assigning coordinates to variables
        x = 0
        y = 131

        ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor (frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
            gray,
            scaleFactor=1.1,
            minNeighbors=25,
            minSize=(50, 50)
            )
#outputing facial sqaure position to terminal          
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 100, 0), 1)
        print (x,y,"---",w,h)

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

#output 23 cannot continue further after DownMax is hit. Continues in other 
direction until switch isn't engaged anymore
    if GPIO.input(27):
        print "Down endstop is hit"
        y = 132
        GPIO.output(23, 0)
        GPIO.output(24, 1)

#output 24 cannot continue further after UpMax is hit. " "        
    if GPIO.input(17):
        print "Up endstop is hit"
        y =132
        GPIO.output(23, 1)
        GPIO.output(24, 0)

#If the face Y-value is less than 130, move motor up     
    if  (y < 130):
        print "Y is less than 130"
        GPIO.output(23, 1)
        GPIO.output(24, 0)
        del y

#If the face Y-value is more than 170, move motor down      
    elif (y > 170):
        print "Y is more than 170"
        GPIO.output(23, 0)
        GPIO.output(24, 1)
        del y

#If a face is not found, default to 131 so motors don't move       
    else:
        y = 131
        print "y is in range"
        GPIO.output(23, 1)
        GPIO.output(24, 1)




finally:

    GPIO.cleanup()


video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When the limit switch is hit, either one, it inches back in the opposite direction to await further coordinates or wait until another user shows up within the webcam stream.

**All I need is it to be multithreaded, any comments or tips are also greatly appreciated.**

Thank You for reading.

Comment: Have you tried a multi-threaded implementation? What makes you believe your code would benefit from running in multiple threads? What portions of your logic would be able to run in parallel?

Comment: That's the thing, I don't truly know. I know it would benefit from a multithread because the entire script utilizes only one core. I want to split these into multiple threads to use the full processing power of my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Well, the thing about multi-threaded applications is that they are only better-performing on certain machines and only when the application has been written to take advantage of parallel processing accordingly. To start, do you have any ideas about how you could possibly split your program into two routines that could execute simultaneously? Are you sure the model of the Raspberry Pi you are using even has multiple cores? Check [here](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/raspberrypi-models-comparison) to verify.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the verification site, I found it does indeed have 4 cores as it is the 3b+.  In order to split it into multiple routines, I would optimally want the face detection and the face positions to run separately so they are not dependent on one another and thereby waiting on the face detection.

Comment: My suggestion would be to break up your program into smaller functions and then take account of what data you need to pass between the separate routines. Then, if you are satisfied with the separation, you can try to create two threads and provide the two functions that you want to run (put loops in the functions) to the threads. Look over [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects) if you need help.

Comment: Seems like the GPIO control loop should be a separate thread/process. Use a queue or pipe to feed it commands. Having it as a separate process which perhaps reads plain text commands from standard input would make this simple to test on its own. Spawning a secondary process and feeding its stdin is fairly simple.

Comment: So I took apart my code and isolated what is really slowing it down. The process of face = face.Cascade etc is really slowing it down. I commented out this snippet and replaced it with face = [] which makes it run significantly faster. Once I rerun the script and check the task manager, it runs at 25%, 1/4 of the CPU. Even if I run this in a separate thread, it will bog down a single core. The GPIO process based off of the Y value is trivial to run for the Pi; virtually nothing for it. I might try and rewrite this program in C++ or C# to overcome the GIL. I will keep y'all updated.